# Odata result order changed after apply ODataQueryOptions

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

After applying ODataQueryOptions my query result order changed even I config to ignore orderby, and I realize this only happens when I using the $expand parameter, so what happened here and how to keep result order in my case.

```
// query
odata/category?$expand=parent($select=Name)

// model
public class Category {
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public Category Parent {get; set;}
  public Guid ParentId {get; set;}
}

// controller
public IActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Category> oDataOptions)
{
    var data = _categoryService.GetAll(); // get data
    var result = oDataOptions.ApplyTo(data, AllowedQueryOptions.OrderBy);

    return this.Ok(result); // this result has different order than data above
}
```